# Get type of form element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, types

I have a form with some inputs and selects. I want to get the type of element on its click with jQuery. I know I can use `attr("input")` to get if the element is radio, checkbox or text but what about `selects` and `textarea`?

Is there a overall function like `.type()` to get it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to select all input elements.

You could try something such as...

```
$('#your-form').find(':input').click(function() {
    var type = this.type || this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    alert(type);
});
```

For `input` elements, this should give you their `type` attribute, such as `text`, `radio`, `checkbox`, etc.

For `select` and `textarea` elements, it should give you the tag name such as `select` or `textarea`.

Comment: Well this is definitely much better than my solution..+1

Comment: Will work except with selects, it's type is `select-one`! see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yqrKV/3/) JSFiddle

Comment: Hi alex, sorry of bothering you, but you can just write `var type = this.type;` if you don't care if selects type will be `select-one`

Answer (score 6):

First `.attr('input')` won't give you the type, use this for inputs:

```
var type = $('input').attr('type')
```

For inputs, select  and textarea:

```
$('#formId :input').click(function() {
    alert(this.tagName != 'INPUT' ? this.tagName : this.type);
});​
```

`:input` selector [docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> Description: Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yqrKV/5)**

Comment: Also javascript .type property gives the global type of element. `$("#elm")[0].type`

Comment: @arunes. except of select, it's type is `select-one`!

Comment: How is this answer better from what Alex has answered

Comment: @Alice. First, I answered first.. Second, the type of select is `select-one` while he wan't `select`

Comment: @hd. It works for them all. Check the DEMO I added to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the element type (input, select, div, span etc):

```
var elementType = $(this).prop('tagName');
```

Checking for specific element type:

```
var is_element_input = $(this).is("input"); //true or false
```

Getting the input type (`input type="button"` etc)

```
var inputType = $(this).attr('type');
```

Answer (score 0):

Selects and textareas are different tags. Use `tagName`.

```
element.tagName
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all your elements a classname say "checktype" and then use:-

```
$(".checktype").click(function(){
  alert(this.tagName);
})
```